# When I press back in the browser, why is a button now missing it's disabled attribute?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, back

I go to a page. A particular button (let's call it button A) that allows the user to continue checking out is currently disabled (as it should be).

I click on another button that leads me to another page to input my address details. After I have done this, the disabled button on the previous will be enabled once I am sent back there.

However, instead of filling in my address details, I press the browser BACK button and return to the previous screen. Button A is no longer disabled. It doesn't even have a disabled attribute when I inspect via the browser. If I refresh the browser, button A is disabled again.

This is the code for the button, part of a `simple_form_for`

`= f.button :button, "Continue to checkout options", class: "btn btn-primary btn-rounded shopping-methods-continue js-checkout-submit", disabled: @basket.requires_address?`

`@basket.requires_address?` is not being called when I go BACK.

I have tried hardcoding `disabled: "disabled"` to see what would happen, but it still doesn't even have a disabled attribute after pressing BACK.

Is there a problem with the caching of this page?

I have dug around the project, in perticular the javascript side of things. `js-checkout-submit` is not affected by any code.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: If you are using turbolinks then it is most likely caching the page. https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#understanding-caching

Comment: No need to put "(Rails)" in your title. That's what tags are for.

Comment: Thanks @max I will have a further read on the topic, it's not something i've touched before!

Answer (score 0):

So, we solved the problem by using turbolinks.

We gave the button a new class of `js-disable-button`.

And then added these instructions at the bottom of the code (coffeescript):

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', () ->
  if "#{@basket.requires_address?}"
    $('.js-disable-button').attr('disabled': 'disabled');
```

So basically, the `@basket.requires_address?` check is performed every time the page is loaded, even when pressing BACK. And the button is disabled if the check returns `true`.

This has provided a solution, however I never really figured out why the problem was occurring in the first place.